# 1 to N relationship

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

Let's say there is a (Head of School) that manages at least one academic  (1 to N) and both are mandotory. Academic has academic ID  as a primary key and other attributes and Head of School only has one attribute which is secretaryName. But SecretaryName is just an attribute.. It's not primary key in diagram. If I convert that statement to relational schema can I write secretaryName as foreign key ?

Academic(academic_ID, academicName, title, secretaryName)

As far as I know, there have to be primary key in both entites in order to create foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that every relation must have a primary key.

In a 1:N relationship that involves two relations it's obvious what happens. Suppose we have two relations; let's call them A and B and say that every A has at least one B. This means that the primary key of B matches with a Foreign Key in A.

In your case the only difference is that the relation is connected to itself, so academic_ID is both the Primary Key and a Foreign Key. So mark it as such on your diagram.

When you map this design to a database you will need something like this:

```
Supervises (manager_ID, subordinate_ID)
```

to model the relationship. Here both attributes are Foreign Keys and together they form a composite primary key.